# laravel dynamic relationship property performance and alternative way

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

I have a question about the dynamic relationship properties, suppose there are `user` and `address` model.

```
public function address(){
    return $this->hasMany(Address::class);
}
```

I want to ask `$user->address` will cause N+1 problems , therefore, we may use eager load, but when I call `$user->address()->get()` will also cause N+1 problems, is it a good performance?

Another question is that what is the better way to get the list of address with specific user?

I want to get only the address data without the user data, therefore, I dont want to use eager load.

Comment: what do you mean by `get only the address data without user data`, when you already user data in `$user`.

Comment: This is because if i use eager load , i will get the data of user and the address data. Therefore, i want to know how to get only the addresss like $user->address()->get() .But $user->address()->get() will run many queries when number of address increase.

Comment: If you want to get the address without the user, then you have to load addresses in the controller instead of loading the user. Therefore you can create a separate function in your Repository. But for a real solution we need to see more code...

Comment: Then you should write a simple query to fetch the addresses using user_id.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want list of user addresses without user data then simply do this:

```
Address::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the addresses without fetching the user data (still need the user id)

Here an example no matter the type of relation.

```
$userId = 1;
$adresses = Address::whereHas('user', function($user) use ($userId) {
    $user->where('id', '=', $userId);
})->get();
```

If the relation is known to be one to many: Use [@May Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66636749/4369919)

Comment: So what is the purpose of dynamic relationship property with hasMany relationship?

Comment: @yuk explain it more plainly. what do you mean by "dynamic relationship property". Are you asking what is the difference between `$user->address` and `$user->address()->get()` ?

Answer (score -1):

I find my answer is that

```
User::with('address')->find($id)->address
```

I think it is a better answer get the address list of a user.

Comment: there is no difference between  `$user->address` or `User::with('address')->find($id)->address ` except that in the second one, you lose the user object that you query

Comment: i mean the performance . the performane of this one is much better then the before because of eager load. it handle the n+1 problems.

Comment: If it's the performance you're after, then take @MAY solution or mine, both of them do run only one query. Your solution runs 2 queries, one for the user and another for the adresses